# Minimal surface representation from a 3D contour

Tags: geometry, interpolation, minimal-surfaces

I have a set of 3D points defining a 3D contour, as shown below. The points in this contour lie in their best-fit plane and I want to obtain a 3D triangular mesh representation of the surface inside this contour.

[image]

Doing some research I found that this is basically a minimal surface problem and its solution is related with the [Biharmonic Equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BiharmonicEquation.html). I also found that the [Thin-plate spline](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ThinPlateSpline.html) is the fundamental solution to this equation.

So my question is: is it correct to try to interpolate the contour points (as shown above) using thin-plate splines so as to obtain the corresponding minimal surface? Is it possible to make such an interpolation on a sparse dataset (given by the 3D contour)?

Thanks!
Miguel

Comment: This is a cross post from http://stackoverflow.com/q/16625316/1468366 and also posted on http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/7268 where it even got an answer.